# Do I need to use -o when I run g++?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, g++

I have a very small c++ program that consists of two files: `main.cpp` and `something.cpp`. I'd like to compile my program using `g++` in the OS X Terminal. Here's what I've tried:

```
> g++ main.cpp something.cpp
> ./a.out
```

**Is this correct?** I've come across examples that use the `-o` flag. I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: If you add a -o, such as `g++ main.cpp something.cpp -o executable`, then it will create a compiled executable file with the name *executable* in the current directory. If you omit the -o flag, g++ will output to the preset file name *a.out*

Comment: Please mention which part of the documentation about that option you didn't understand when trying to decide for yourself whether it was necessary. Without an understanding of what's wrong with the current documentation, we can't hope for it to improve.

Comment: However, using the `a.out` program name is poor taste today. 15 years ago, `a.out` was also a file format for executable binaries, which has been replaced by ELF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-o` option is not required. If not specified, the default behavior is to put an executable file in "a.out":

> -o file
>   Place output in file file.  This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable
>   file, an object file, an assembler
>   file or preprocessed C code.
>
> If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its
>   assembler file in source.s, a
>   precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

So yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Does it work? That's a pretty good indication of correctness! The `-o` flag allows you to specify a file name so the executable is not named `a.out`